# RichEditBox not working properly on Dark Theme

Tags: uwp, themes, richeditbox

I am developing an app, which offers Rich Text editing capabilities, with light and dark theme.
When swithing to the dark theme, I am unable to view the text in focus, and any text coloring gets lost when switching focus.
I have created a simple text case that has two rich text boxes, a button to change the selected text to red, and two button to switch between light and dark theme.
I am applying a styling to the rich edit box, but it looks like is ignoring the x:Key="TextControlForegroundFocused", or maybe computing SystemBaseHighColor prior applying the theme cahnges.

XAML

```
<Page.Resources>

    <!-- RichEditBox Styling-->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlForegroundFocused" Color="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlForegroundDisabled" Color="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBackgroundFocused" Color="{ThemeResource TextControlForeground}"/>

</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel Name="_Root" >

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Button Content="Red" Click="OnRed"/>
        <Button Content="Dark Theme" Click="OnDark"/>
        <Button Content="Light Theme" Click="OnLight"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <RichEditBox Name="RichEditor1" Style="{ThemeResource EditBoxStyle}" Width="250" Height="200"/>
        <RichEditBox Name="RichEditor2" Style="{ThemeResource EditBoxStyle}" Width="250" Height="200"/>
    </StackPanel>

</StackPanel>
```

C#

```
    private void OnRed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RichEditor1.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Colors.Red;
        RichEditor2.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Colors.Red;
    }

    private void OnDark(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _Root.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
        _Root.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }
    private void OnLight(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _Root.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light;
        _Root.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }
```

Any suggestion on how to make this work?

Comment: 'unable to view the text in focus' It's because you set _Root.Background to black and rewrite the 'TextControlForegroundFocused' to 'SystemBaseHighColor'. When you switch to 'Dark', they're all black. That's why you cannot see the text in focus.

Comment: 'text coloring gets lost when switching focus.' I could reproduce this question, I've reported to the relevant team, they're investigating it.

Comment: SystemBaseHighColor suppose to be white (#FFFFFFFF)
 when the theme is Dark. So TextControlForegroundFocused should be visible on the black background, but it is not. Looks to me like the value of SystemBaseHighColor is not computed based on the current Dark theme.  Even if I remove the overwriting style for TextControlForegroundFocused, the text is not visible when in focus. Would you have a suggestion on how to change the code to make it work when switching the theme?

Comment: Actually it looks like any setting for TextControlForegroundFocused is ignored.

Comment: I removed all your custom style for the RicheditBox, when RicheditBox get focused, the foreground will be changed to white, I can see the text. See [Screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoI4pKdRYn8KnG_EPB-ym9n9ibXq)

Comment: Sure, but when I edit the background become white and the foreground black. it doesn't seen to be possible to have a RichEditBox with black background during editing, which I think is pretty odd. I would consider this a bug actually.